# Zend_Auth using Zend_Session instead of default storage?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cookies, zend-auth, zend-session

I was reading through [this tutorial](http://robertbasic.com/blog/login-example-with-zend_auth/), and at one point in the code, the user info is retrieved from the database and a session is created for the user:

```
// the default storage is a session with namespace Zend_Auth  
$authStorage = $auth->getStorage();  
$authStorage->write($userInfo);
```

I tried this, but this session expires once the browser is closed. So my question is how do I combine this with Zend_Session to create a cookie that lasts for 20 days or something? I can't figure it out through the Zend_Session documentation..

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Zend_Session::rememberMe($seconds);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix 2 different tasks. One task you have is "authentication", another is "remember me feature".

So don't try to solve them in one shot.

For remember me store **another** cookie with some **random hash** and keep a table that assotiates each random hash with particular `user_id`.

Also, it is a lot of discussions about "remember me" implementations here at SO: http://www.google.ru/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+remember+me&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox